# Output function's array values in MATLAB's GUI

Tags: arrays, matlab, user-interface, output

How to output function's array in *Matlab's GUI* function?
I have a function:

```
function p = PushButtonPressed(h, eventdata)
p=[2 4 5;];
```

how to output `p` or assign its value globally, i.e other functions of *GUI* can input that as argument or can be used in current *workspace*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can use `handles` struct for that. You can use a `global` variable too, but I think for a single GUI case, it's safer to stick to using `handles` struct solution. Listing out both here.

**Handles Solution, Code**

```
function p = PushButtonPressed(h, eventdata,handles)

p=[2 4 5;];
handles.p = p;

%%// Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

return;


function p = some_other_function(h, eventdata,handles)

%%// Retrieve the previously saved value of p
p = handles.p;

%%// Do something with p

return;
```

**Global variable Solution, Code**

```
function p = PushButtonPressed(h, eventdata)

global p

p=[2 4 5;];

return;


function p = some_other_function(h, eventdata)

global p

%%// Do something with p

return;
```

Comment: The both piece of codes doesn't work for me, p array is defined well with in the function only.

Comment: Some error? If so, what does the error say, otherwise tell us more about what/how it didn't work?

Comment: firslty, it simply gives error on undefined hObject as it is not in its arguments, secondaly, it gives values only inside function, second function us unable to use that values.

Comment: So you have your original function - `function p = PushButtonPressed(h, eventdata)`. Does your original code work properly in the first place without `p`? If it does we can proceed to see the issue with `p`?